Number of ways of distributing invitation into envelopes where each envelope may recieve any number of invitations.
Suppose that we have $n$  envelopes, $e_1, e_2, .., e_{n}$ and $n$ invitations $i_1,i_2,.., i_{n} $ with each invitation $i_k$ having corresponding envelope $e_k$.
We are sending out each of these $n$ envelopes to $n$ distinct guests, say, $g_1, g_2, ..., g_n$, with envelope $e_k$ going to guest $g_k$. A guest shows up if and only if they receive their envelope with only their invitation, i.e., they recieve their envelope $e_k$ which contains invitation $i_k$ and only the invitation $i_k$, which is to say, if they recieve an empty envelope, or an envelope with more than one invitation (even if their invitation is one of those included), then they do not show up. Note that each envelope goes to their respective guest, so we need not consider the case in which a guest does not recieve their envelope. Further note that each invitation must go in one of the envelopes and only in one envelope (one invitation cannot go in more than one envelope), though an envelope can be sent empty.
Now let $X$ be the random variable counting the number of guests that show up. We want to evaluate $ \mathbb{P}(X=0)$.
This to me at least has turned out be quite convoluted and complicated. For some added context, this was given to us in the midsemester exam for an introductory course in undergraduate probability theory.
If we consider a subcase of this problem, one in which each envelope may recieve only one invitation, which is to say that none of the envelopes are allowed to go empty, then clearly the number of ways of distributing the invitations in the envelopes so none go in their respective envelope is simply the number of derangements, and thus $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}$.
But we have the additional degree of freedom, which complicates things a fair bit.
For a moment, let's consider the case when $n=3$, then, $ \mathbb{P}(X=0)=1-\mathbb{P}(X=1) -\mathbb{P}(X=2)-\mathbb{P}(X=3)$, now note that $\mathbb{P}(X=3)=1/27$ since total ways of distributing three invitations among three envelopes equal $3^3=27$, also, $\mathbb{P}(X=2)=0$ since exactly two guests cannot show up because that would force the last invitation to go into its respective envelope, and then all three guests show up. Now consider that only one guest shows up, say $g_1$, then $i_1$ goes into $e_1$, and for $i_2,i_3$ we have three cases, one is when $i_2$ goes to $e_3$ and $i_3$ goes to $e_2$, the last two cases are when $i_2,i_3$ both go into either of $e_2,e_3$. So, only one guest shows up in a total of $3+3+3=9$ ways, and hence $\mathbb{P}(X=0)= \frac{27-9-1}{27}=\frac{17}{27}$. This case by itself was tedious enough, and I am not sure how one would go on to generalize this.
My question is, how can we evaluate this probability for the general case.

To summarise, are you saying that the difference from the "normal" problem is that any particular  envelope may contain any number of invitations including all of them, or none of them, but all invitations are sent in the envelope(s)

@trueblueanil Yes, that is so.

@abomasnow Yes, the guest shows up if and only if they receive their envelope with their respective invitation only. All guests receive their envelopes, but an envelope may arrive empty, or with multiple invitations.

Easy enough to compute the expected number of guests who show up, but I agree that getting the exact probabilities seems hard.  I'd try to do it recursively...noting that there are two ways for guest $#n$ to fail.  Either $i_n$ is not put in $e_n$ (which also removes one other guest) or $i_n$ is put in $e_n$ but some number of others invitations are also put in $e_n$ (which also removes some other guests).  Either path ends up creating a "trash" option into which invitations might be tossed. Depending on specifics, the trash option might be more likely than a fixed envelope so...

...the recursive method will need to track the probability of the trash option.  If, say, $3$ extra invitations are sent to $#n$, then those $3$ envelopes are all part of the trash option and invitations may be sent there without subtracting off another guest.  Still doesn't seem to lead to anything great.

@lulu I am not sure if this recursive method takes this into case, but aside from the two ways you mention for guest number $n$ to fail, we also need to take into account when guest number $n$ recieves an empty envelope, since the guest does not show up then either.

That case is covered by my first scenario, since in your situation $i_n$ does not go into $e_n$.

@lulu Yes, I understand it better now. I wonder if we can form a recurrence relation here, that was one of my attempts too, unfortunately, I did not manage much progress.

One good thing about the recursive method is that it shouldn't be hard to automate.  That means that it is should be relatively easy to compute the answer for modest values of $n$.  Presumably the intent was to find something like a closed form solution but it's always good to have lots of examples.

The expected number turning up is easy to find: a particular guest turns up if they get their own invitation and nobody else's so with probability $\frac1n \left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-1}$ so the expected number turning up is  $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-1}$,  As $n$ increases this tends towards $e^{-1}$.  Making the wild guess that the limiting distribution might be Poisson, perhaps $\mathbb P(X=0) \to e^{e^{-1}} \approx 0.692$

Here is an empirical approach with the same answer as abomasnow: $$\mathbb P(X=0) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}(-1)^{n-k} \frac{k^k}{n^n}.$$
To find this, I brute-forced the $n^n$ cases for $n$ up to $8$ using the following R code and found the numbers where nobody attended to be $0, 3, 17, 169, 2079, 31261, 554483, 11336753$ which is essentially OEIS A069856 with an adjustment for signs; apparently this sequence is the inverse binomial transform of $n^n$.
OEIS gives values up to $n=200$ $($about $1.1113\times 10^{460})$ so a probability there of about $0.69156$ which is close to my guess of a limit of $e^{-e^{-1}} \approx 0.6922$ by hoping for something close to a Poisson distribution with mean $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-1}$.
numbersgoing <- function(n){
  going <- matrix(TRUE, nrow=n^n, ncol=n)
  for (i in 1:n){
    invite <- rep(1:n, each=n^(i-1), times=n^(n-i))
    going[,i] <- going[,i] & (invite == i)
    for (j in (1:n)[-i]){
      going[,j] <- going[,j] & (invite != j)
      }
    }
  return(rowSums(going))
  }

n <- 8
peoplegoing <- numbersgoing(n)

# mean(peoplegoing)        ## expected number going
# 0.3926959
(1-1/n)^(n-1)
# 0.3926959
mean(peoplegoing == 0)     ## probability of none going
# 0.6757231
k <- 0:n
sum(choose(n,k)*(-1)^(n-k)*k^k/n^n)
# 0.6757231
table(peoplegoing)         ## table of how many going 
peoplegoing
#        0        1        2        3        4        5        6        8 
# 11336753  4435864   875308   116424    11830      952       84        1 
sum(choose(n,k)*(-1)^(n-k)*k^k)
# 11336753

The Poisson distribution guess looks close: this chart plots the table divided by $n^n$ for $n=8$ as black vertical bars, and shows the Poisson distribution pmf with the same mean of $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-1}$ as red dots.
plot(table(peoplegoing) / n^n)
points(0:n,dpois(0:n,mean(peoplegoing)), col="red")


